# Does "stand" have the meaning of "be helpful for"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, dictionaries

*"something stands somebody in good stead"* is a common idiom, which means "something is helpful for somebody in the present and future".

However, under the entry *"stand"* in the OXFORD dictionary, there is no meaning item equivalent to "be helpful for".

Is there any explanation for *"stand"*'s meaning in the idiom?

Comment: It's more "supports".

Comment: 'Stand' doesn't have an unusual meaning here. Something stands you (places you upright) in good stead (in a good place; an advantageous position). It is like saying, 'You will be well placed (to do something).' 'In his stead', meaning 'in place of him', is a little old fashioned, but 'instead' still means 'in the place of something already mentioned.'

Answer (score 2):

The verb *to stand* is one of the oldest verbs we have in English, dating from 825 ᴀᴅ. The OED gives 350 different senses for this verb, 140 main senses and 210 subsenses. This one isn’t really anything too special.

The particular use you ask about is documented in subsense b of sense 48. This exact sense of the verb *stand* in conjunction with *stead* dates from around 1300 ᴀᴅ, appearing first in the written record as the Middle English of *Cursor Mundi*.

> #### IV. Phrases and idiomatic uses.
>
> 48. **to stand in stead**  *v.*
>
>     - **†a.** To be of use or advantage, to be serviceable or profitable. Also with adjective qualifying *stead*, to be of (little, no, good) avail or service. *Obsolete.*
>     - **b.** More usually with indirect obj. (†rarely with *to*). ***to stand (one) in (good,* etc.) *stead***: to be of service or benefit to; to help or avail. Now only with adj. (*good*, etc.), and that in literary rather than familiar use.
>         
>        <sup>When without epithet, *in stead* was sometimes written or printed as one word.</sup>
>     - **†c.** Similarly ***to stand* (one) *to* (good) *stead***. Also without preposition, ***to stand* (one) *stead***. *Obsolete. rare.*
>     - **†d.** In various other phrases of like meaning, as to ***stand (a person) in force, in profit, in vail, at or to avail***. *to stand (in) stall*: see ꜱᴛᴀʟʟ n.¹ 2b. *Obsolete*.

Notice how they mention that this phrase now occurs mainly in “literary” use rather than in “familiar” use. Here are a few of the older citations they provide for subsense 48b:

> - 1387   J. Trevisa tr. R. Higden *Polychron*. (Rolls) VII. 267   
>   But for it stood hem but litel in stede [L. *sed quia parum profecerunt*].
> - 1665   in Extracts *State Papers* (Friends’ Hist. Soc.) (1912) 3rd Ser. 241   
>   Our good intentions stand us in little stead.
> - 1749   H. Fielding *Tom Jones* II. v. viii. 182   
>   It is then he will find in what mighty Stead that Heathen Goddess..will stand him.
> - 1848   Thackeray *Vanity Fair* liv. 487   A Johnson's Dictionary, which stood them in much stead.
> - 1887   W. Westall tr. ‘A. Laurie’ *Capt. Trafalgar* i. 13   
>   Continual practice stood me in better stead than whole volumes of theory.
> - 1891   *Temple Bar* Oct. 177   
>   His early training..stood him in good stead.

Those all have a personal pronoun as a benefactive indirect object. That’s because one stands ***someone*** that way, so that is the person who benefits from the standing.